# Lua 5.2: undefined symbols when using luaL_dofile()

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, linker, lua

I was trying to do some simple Lua 5.2 embedding using the following C++ code:

```
void dnLuaRunner::Exec(string file)
{
    // Initialize the lua interpreter.
    lua_State * L;
    L = luaL_newstate();

    // Load lua libraries.
    static const luaL_Reg luaLibs[] =
    {
        {"math", luaopen_math},
        {"base", luaopen_base},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    // Loop through all the functions in the array of library functions
    // and load them into the interpreter instance.
    const luaL_Reg * lib = luaLibs;
    for (; lib->func != NULL; lib++)
    {
        lib->func(L);
        lua_settop(L, 0);
    }

    // Run the file through the interpreter instance.
    luaL_dofile(L, file.c_str());

    // Free memory allocated by the interpreter instance.
    lua_close(L);
}
```

The first part is some basic initialization and code for loading some standard library modules, but when I called `luaL_dofile(...)` it seemed to be raising some errors for undefined symbols. `luaL_dofile` is a macro that uses functions like `luaL_loadfile` and `lua_pcall`, so it didn't look extremely scary that I was getting the following linker errors:

```
  "_luaL_loadfilex", referenced from:
      dnLuaRunner::Exec(std::string) in dnLuaRunner.cc.o
  "_lua_pcallk", referenced from:
      dnLuaRunner::Exec(std::string) in dnLuaRunner.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I was linking `liblua.a` correctly in the Makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you need to add `-lm` along with `-llua` and they both **must** be after the file you want to compile, like so:

```
# or clang++ works too
$ g++ ... foofy.c -llua -lm
```

I have also seen circumstances where you must use `-ldl` at the end as well.

Comment: as I remeber, `-ldl` was required too. Linker options, nothing fency.

Comment: @Kamiccolo I tried just `-llua` and `-ldl` too but just `-llua` and `-lm` worked for me fine.

Comment: @beakr `-lm` is for the `math.h` header file right? I've been told that I need to include `-lm` when compiling if I used `math.h` functions in my .c file. But it seems like I didn't have to include it when compiling with gcc. So, is it compiler specific?

Comment: @YickLeung I'm pretty sure `math.h` is part of the stdlib and doesn't need linking. I wrote this from the perspective of C++ compiled with `g++`, `clang++` or something of the sort. **Edit**: I think `-lm` is for a library of math functions made by AMD that is different than the standard `math.h`.